# HAVING & BETWEEN query returns blank values

Tags: mysql

**SAMPLE DATA**

---

```
INSERT INTO `employee` (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES 
('1', 'john', 'doe'),
('2', 'joan', 'doe'),
('3', 'jeff', 'doe'),
('4', 'george', 'doe'),
('5', 'jessica', 'doe'),
('6', 'james', 'doe'),
('7', 'justin', 'doe'),
('8', 'jody', 'doe');

INSERT INTO `shift` (`started_at`, `ended_at`, `employee_id`) VALUES
('2017-11-01 08:00:00', '2017-11-01 12:00:00', 1),
('2017-11-01 12:00:00', '2017-11-01 16:00:00', 2),
('2017-11-02 08:00:00', '2017-11-02 12:00:00', 3),
('2017-12-25 12:00:00', '2017-12-25 16:00:00', 6),
('2017-12-25 12:00:00', '2017-12-25 16:00:00', 3),
('2017-12-28 19:00:00', '2017-12-28 23:00:00', 5),
('2017-12-23 12:00:00', '2017-12-23 14:00:00', 5);
```

---

**EXPECTED/WANTED OUTCOME FROM QUERY**

---

All entries besides Jessica Doe should be displayed (as she breaks the 8 hours in the past 2 week rule)

```
('2017-11-01 08:00:00', '2017-11-01 12:00:00', 1),
('2017-11-01 12:00:00', '2017-11-01 16:00:00', 2),
('2017-11-02 08:00:00', '2017-11-02 12:00:00', 3),
('2017-12-25 12:00:00', '2017-12-25 16:00:00', 6),
('2017-12-25 12:00:00', '2017-12-25 16:00:00', 3),
```

Thanks.

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is nice, but you should edit your question an dprovide sample data and desired results.  For instance, my expectation from the first sentence is that you are looking for a trigger.

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry about that i thought that would qualify for that requirement, is my edit OK?

Comment: currently focusing on the 8 hours in a 2 day period part? shouldn't be 8 hours in 2 weeks? can you provide ids for the employees?

Comment: Hi Sia,

Sorry about that, typo on my end - you're correct - 8 hours in 2 weeks. The id's auto increment so that's why I had left them out but I will now updated it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your 2week where in where  condition

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, SUM(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.started_at, 
s.ended_at))) as shift_hours
FROM employee e, shift s
WHERE e.id = s.employee_id and started_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW() 
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING shift_hours < 8
```

The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks Kiamoz, but this still leaves me with an issue, I would like it so that the query selects all of the employees that have not done over 8 hours of work in the past 2 weeks.

Essentially selecting every employee on the database that has not completed over 8 hours of work in the last 2 week period, am I going about this in the right way currently?

Comment: there is an issue in your EXPECTED/WANTED , ('2018-01-01 08:00:00', '2018-01-01 12:00:00', 1), is not past 2 week , it's future @entity please let me knew excally what you need

Comment: Sorry about that, my mistake - I have now corrected the data.

The query should select ALL employees, except ones that have over 8 shift_hours in the past 2 weeks as of the query being run.

The database should NOT select an employee that has done work within the previous 24 hours of the query being run.

Am I on the right lines with my thinking? Hopefully what I am explaining makes sense, sorry if it doesn't, let me know!

Comment: hey entity , be careful all data you entered is about past 2 week , and if you sum hours you can get result ., why you don't select this row ? ('2017-12-23 12:00:00', '2017-12-23 14:00:00', 5); ??

Answer (score 0):

I may be WAY off base here, MySQL isn't me specialty.  But...  In the SQLfiddle, if you remove you HAVING clause (the last line that you mentioned in your question), you see that every record shows more than 8 hours.  This means that your HAVING clause is working correctly.  It's preventing any records with more than 8 hours from being returned.  In this case, "HAVING shift_hours < 8" is doing exactly what it's supposed to do.  It looks to me like something in your aggregation is not doing what you think/expect it is.

Note:  If you move the logical comparison ( < 8) to the end of the line, you get the same result as if you remove the line.

Comment: Hey M C,

Thanks for taking a look! Yep that is correct, and I believe it is working correctly as to how I have written in, BUT, I am trying to make it say essentially this "SELECT all engineers that have worked less than 8 hours in the past 2 weeks" The current will only return people who have done any work in the past 2 weeks AND have less than 8 hours. I am really struggling to think about how I can accomplish this, once again, thanks a lot for taking a look!